# Sensitive middle-button (mouse)

Tags: xorg, gnome, mouse-wheel

Whenever I click on the middle-button on my mouse-wheel, it seems that multiple click events are being sent in succession.

Case in point: when I middle-click a bookmark folder in Chrome (to open up all the bookmarks in tabs), Chrome opens up the same set of bookmarks three times. This is very annoying.

Is there a way in X or Gnome to detune the sensitivity of my mouse's middle button to prevent multiple click events from being sent? Maybe like a double-click speed adjustment for the middle-button?

Comment: I have the same problem, using a laptop with the mouse plugged in. And it is absolutely no worn or defect mouse, a have tried several mouses (or mice?) but they all have the same click function in the mousewheel causing a mouseclick while scrolling.
And i would very much want to turn off that function, who knows the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this usually happens when the mouse button contacts are worn off... although it usually happens with the left button first.

I would test the mouse on another machine or plug another mouse into this machine and see if the problem goes away in either case. This will help you to exclude (or confirm) hardware malfunction.

Comment: You're right, that could be the cause. I'll test it on a different machine. Thanks.